# Settings breakpoints inside callbacks on Spotify's dev tools often crashes the app

Tags: javascript, spotify, devtools

While debugging JavaScript code using the developers tools, setting a breakpoint inside a callback and evaluating expressions (either using the debugger's watch functionality or simply trying to evaluate expressions of the current scope in the console) almost always crashes the app.

This seems to happen specially on browser fired callbacks, like ajax requests or DOM events, more particularly events fired via onreadystatechange or DOMContentLoaded, and never on callbacks fired by our own code (not entirely sure of other DOM events).

This is really annoying as usually when I'm able to crash the app like this, I can reproduce it consistently every time, and it stops me from using the developer tools for debugging, having to resort to peppering my code with console.logs everywhere.

**Update**

I've looked at OSX's Console.app logs and I found this right when the app crashes. This probably explains it.

28/03/2012 10:21:30.456 [0x0-0x3cb3cb].com.spotify.client: [0328/102130:ERROR:browser_devtools_client.cc(55)] Not implemented reached in virtual void BrowserDevToolsClient::activateWindow()